# Find all table's name in one Query or SQL command

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like to find all table's names in my T-SQL command. My command can be a Select, Update, Delete, Insert, Merge or Truncate.

I can use C#. But I don't really how can I find them because there is a lot of possibility.

For example: I can have a select like select below:

```
SELECT
    <Schemaname>.<TableName1>.Field1,
    <TableName2>.Field2,
    Field3,
    Field4 = ( Select .. FROM <TableName6> WHERE ... )
FROM 
    <TableName1> , <TableName2>
INNER JOIN 
    <TableName3> AS TableName4 ON .....
WHERE ....
    <TableName2>.Field3 in ( SELECT ... FROM TableName5 )
```

The list that I am looking should has these table's names

```
TableName1,TableName2,TableName3,TableName5,TableName6
```

TableName4 is an alias name in this case and it does not present a real name of a table in database.

I have the command where I have used a table name with schema name and an other table without schema name and also I have the alias for some of my tables and the alias can be like a table name that I have really in my database.

Comment: Why don't you use just: SELECT * FROM sys.Tables ?

Comment: I am not looking for all tables names in my database. I am looking for the tables names that I have used in my command. for example i can have 1000 tables in my database by in my select command i have used just 3 of them. i would like to find them

Comment: Interesting , @Ardalan - can you please let me know what is the purpose here.

Comment: This is impossible to get 100% correct and exhaustive. What happens if you have a function? And that function pulls data from a view? And that view pulls from other tables? And even in your example above there are SO many possibilities. You would be better off creating this as a stored procedure and then looking at sys.depends. But even that isn't exhaustive as it only goes as deep as this query, not the other objects dependencies being referenced.

Comment: @SeanLange : If there is a view, I dont want go more far

Comment: @AbdulAzeez : honestly I have a lot of SSIS packages. I have found all command in my packages. Now, I need to make a list for all tables name that I have in all my commands.

Comment: Right...and like I said even just in the query you posted it is nearly impossible with just t-sql. You are trying to mimic part of what the parser does in a single query.

Comment: Your last comment proves my point. What good is a list of affected tables if it isn't complete?

Comment: @TabAlleman: As i have mentioned in previous command, I have several package in SSIS. I would like to know that i am using which table in which package. Right now i can do that by searching in XML cod of all package and I have found all command text.

Comment: I think you've gotten as close as you can get programmatically.   A human being will have to read the command texts, and make a list of the tables used.   No sure way around it.

Comment: It would be FAR more accurate and fast to just open the command and manually look at the code.

Comment: @SeanLange: In reality i have more than 1000 packages and in each package there are a lot of script task and lookup and data flow and .... I would like to find in which package we are using one table for some raison. It is not possible to open all package's componnets

Comment: Well good luck. Doing this purely with t-sql is incredibly difficult. And by difficult I mean nearly impossible. It will take days and days to get a t-sql script that even comes close to being accurate for this. There are just too many possibilities. Unless the table name you are looking for is so unique you would feel comfortable just searching your code for that table name. Anything else is only going to get you close.

Comment: @SeanLange We don't have any naming convention. What I have done is that I have created a list of all table's names in sys.tables and then i search <SchemaName>.<TableName> in my command line. but the problem starts when I have a command where we didn't use schema name before table name.

Comment: @SeanLange That is a good answer. I think i can fix some of the problem with you idea

Comment: Ouch. With over 1,000 SSIS packages perhaps it is time to start making your code more manageable.

Comment: One you should not use old style joins, two this is hard, three TSQL is not the right tool.

Comment: You need tsql parser for that. You can try this one: https://github.com/bruce-dunwiddie/tsql-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this purely with t-sql is incredibly difficult. And by difficult I mean nearly impossible. It will take days and days to get a t-sql script that even comes close to being accurate for this. There are just too many possibilities. Unless the table name you are looking for is so unique you would feel comfortable just searching your code for that table name. Anything else is only going to get you close. Good luck!!!

This is impossible to get 100% correct and exhaustive. What happens if you have a function? And that function pulls data from a view? And that view pulls from other tables?

And even in your example above there are SO many possibilities. You would be better off creating this as a stored procedure and then looking at **sys.depends**.

But even that isn't exhaustive as it only goes as deep as this query, not the other objects dependencies being referenced

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure I really understand what you are trying to achieve but here are my 2 cents:

Assuming that you can extract the SQL command using some code (can't help if you need THAT code) from your many SSIS packages.
Based on that, I would

- use a reference list of all the database objects and search for each of them through your SQLCommand (extracted from your SSIS package)
- Build a list of the all the name strings found (list of objects,
  could be tables, views, functions, stored procedures)
- Then use that list to find the dependent objects in your DB (if you
  need to go that deep)

  select DISTINCT s1.class_desc, s1.object_id, referenced_major_id, OBJECT_NAME(s1.object_id) AS ObjName , OBJECT_NAME(s2.object_id) AS ObjName2 
  from sys.sql_dependencies s1
  INNER JOIN sys.objects s2 ON s2.object_id = s1.referenced_major_id
- Put all that into your result table
- Move on to next SSIS package

Would that work for you?

B

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i have used the answer of @sean Lange.